# How to return "True" if nth greatest value in column of data frame is a number >=x

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   prod_id  Fac     demand_near_wh
0   45906   Fac-1   0
1   45906   Fac-2   51
2   45906   Fac-3   30
3   45906   Fac-4   10
4   45906   Fac-5   52
5   48402   Fac-1   0
6   48402   Fac-2   72
7   48402   Fac-3   39
8   48402   Fac-4   14
9   48402   Fac-5   6
```

I want to create four new columns titled `"2nd_wh"`, `"3rd_wh"`, and `"4th_wh"`, and `"5th_wh"`. For each of these new columns I want to return `"True"` if the value in `"demand_near_wh"` is the nth highest number (i.e. 3rd highest, 4th highest, 5th highest) and `>=30` for a given `prod_id`, otherwise return `"False"`.

For example, in the `"3rd_wh"` column it will return `"True"` if the value in the `"demand_near_wh"` is the 3rd highest value for a given product_id and is `>=30`, otherwise `"False"`. In the `"4th_wh"` column, it will return `"True"` if the value in the `"demand_near_wh"` for a given `prod_id` is the 4th highest value and is `>=30`, otherwise `"False"`, etc.

The final output should look like this:

```
   prod_id  Fac     demand_near_wh 1st_wh 2nd_wh 3rd_wh 4th_wh  5th_wh  
0   45906   Fac-1   0               False  False  False  False  True 
1   45906   Fac-2   51              False  True   False  False  False
2   45906   Fac-3   30              False  False  True   False  False
3   45906   Fac-4   10              False  False  False  True   False
4   45906   Fac-5   52              True   False  False  False  False
5   48402   Fac-1   0               False  False  False  False  True
6   48402   Fac-2   72              True   False  False  False  False
7   48402   Fac-3   39              False  True   False  False  False
8   48402   Fac-4   14              False  False  False  True   False
9   48402   Fac-5   6               False  False  False  True   False
```

I've tried the code below, which worked for the "1st_wh" column..

```
df['1st_wh']=df.groupby(['prod_id'])['perc_dem_near_wh'].transform('max')==df['perc_dem_near_wh']
print(df.head(5))

   prod_id Facility  perc_dem_near_wh  1st_wh
0    45906    Fac-1                 0   False
1    45906    Fac-2                51   False
2    45906    Fac-3                30   False
3    45906    Fac-4                10   False
4    45906    Fac-5                52    True
```

However, when I populate the column "2nd_wh" with the code below, I get an error that says `"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I'm very new to Python and don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance for anyone that can help.

```
df['2nd_wh'] = df['perc_dem_near_wh'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x >= 30 and df['perc_dem_near_wh'].nlargest(2) else'False')
print (df.head(15))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: try to change `and` to `&`